# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'

Tags: python, operating-system

When I do:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.uname()
```

I get an attribute error which looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    os.uname()
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
```

How can I fix this is my python broken or something else because in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname).

Comment: `Availability: recent flavors of Unix.`

Comment: It's not available on all OS's as pointed out. What info are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've run your code the exact same way in IDLE on Windows 10 and got the same result.

```
>>> print(os.uname())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(os.uname())
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
```

And as @Joran Beasley pointed out, this function is only [available in certain operating systems](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.uname).

From an online compiler:

```
posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='Check', release='5.4.10-x86_64-linode132', version='#1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 9 21:17:12 UTC 2020', machine='x86_64')
```

If you want to get current os, I recommend the `platform` module.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0'
```

Some people prefer using `os` module, but `platform` is much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the `uname` function only works on some Unix systems. If you are on Windows, you can use the `uname` function in the platform module, which returns a similar result.

```
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.uname())
uname_result(system='Windows', node='DESKTOP-OVU16P3', release='10', version='10.0.19042', machine='AMD64')
```