# Django oscar docker: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'

Tags: django, docker, pipenv, django-oscar, pipenv-install

i used git clone https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar, then i used

```
pipenv install
```

and i got

```
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname' this error as well as this 
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError:
Command errored out with exit status 1:
python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this does not have a lot to do with docker but more with the host OS (win 10 in this case).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241374/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-uname) describes in more detail but it comes down to the fact that uname is not available on windows. Since docker containers use the kernels from the host OS they are run on, in your case this will error out.

The same error will appear if you run these commands in Windows 10 under the python Idle environment.