# Python errors on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, error-handling, uwsgi

[image]

So this code was written on Linux and now I try to run it on Windows and I am getting such errors, what should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241374/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-uname

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241374/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-uname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only available on Unix. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname

Not sure if `sys.platform` fits your needs.